# Jhispter ssl api authentication Ionic PWA deployed to firebase

Tags: api, spring-boot, ssl, ionic-framework, progressive-web-apps

I have a secure Jhispter app here 
https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8050/#/ and I can login

```
server:
    # port: 8060
    port: 8050
    ssl:
       key-store: classpath:nms-PKCS-12.p12
       key-store-password:  MYPASS
       key-store-type: PKCS12
       key-alias: nmsapi
```

When I try Login to my Ionic PWA that I deployed to firebase here
https://gotopnms.firebaseapp.com

it says:

```
[Error] XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8050/#//authenticate due to access control checks.


error: XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent    
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: null
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
lengthComputable: false
loaded: 0
position: 0
returnValue: true
srcElement: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8050/#//authenticate", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: Array, __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrScheduled: true, …}

target: XMLHttpRequest {__zone_symbol__xhrSync: false, __zone_symbol__xhrURL: "https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8050/#//authenticate", __zone_symbol__loadfalse: Array, __zone_symbol__errorfalse: null, __zone_symbol__xhrScheduled: true, …}

timeStamp: 69734
total: 0
totalSize: 0
type: "error"
XMLHttpRequestProgressEvent Prototype
headers: HttpHeaders {normalizedNames: Map, lazyUpdate: null, headers: Map, has: function, get: function, …}

message: "Http failure response for https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8050/#//authenticate: 0 Unknown Error"

name: "HttpErrorResponse"
ok: false
status: 0
statusText: "Unknown Error"
url: "https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8050/#//authenticate"

[Log] Login error – HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", …} (main.js, line 2050)

HttpErrorResponse {headers: HttpHeaders, status: 0, statusText: "Unknown Error", url: "https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8050/#//authenticate", ok: false, …}HttpErrorResponse
```

but I have cors conf like this:

```
cors:
        allowed-origins: "*"
        allowed-methods: "*"
        allowed-headers: "*"
        exposed-headers: "Authorization,Link,X-Total-Count"
        allow-credentials: true
        max-age: 1800
```

and if I use not secure urlAPI: 'http://35.230.141.174:8060/api', in m y localhost, I can login in my Ionic PWA https://youtu.be/yIZ6jY2aAXs with no cors problems

My ionic environment

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  // urlAPI: 'http://35.230.141.174:8060/api',
  urlAPI: 'https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8050/#',
  socketConf: {
    url: 'http://35.230.141.174:3050',
    options: { reconnection: true, reconnectionDelay: 3000, timeout: 60000 }
  },
```

Note: I didn't secure yet the socket. So they are also giving error.

There is something I need to do with nginx?
(I am not using nginx, but I know the Debian server has it )

I saw somewhere that it could be replacing rest api posts with get, but I don't know where...

Maybe I am missing some Jhispter configuration ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's solved. Maybe can help someone. 
I have to close VSCode to ionic build work and 
I had in environment

```
urlAPI: 'https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8050/#',
```

instead of

```
urlAPI: 'https://api.nms.blaucomm.co.uk:8050/api',
```